# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames Nextjs with S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, dns, nextjs-image

I get this error in my Nextjs Application where I use an image with next/image from my s3 bucket:

```
FetchError: request to https://bucketname.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/1671375836114 failed, reason: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: bucketname.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-control.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3-control.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-control.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3-control.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-accesspoint.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-accesspoint.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?